# Getting errors while using Win32 library functions in my Ada code

Tags: winapi, ada

I'm using following statements in my Ada code:-

```
with Win32;
with Win32.Winbase;  use Win32.Winbase;
with Win32.Winnt;    use Win32.Winnt;
```

But getting the errors:-

```
"file win32.ads not found" 
"file win32-winbase.ads not found" 
"file win32-winnt.ads not found"
```

Please suggest what's wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You’re getting these errors because you haven’t installed the package that contains the missing files (or, perhaps, you’ve installed them somewhere the compiler can’t find them).

The Win32Ada package is on [Github](https://github.com/AdaCore/win32ada).

Or you might be able to find a prebuilt binary installer to match your compiler at [AdaCore’s Community Edition site](https://www.adacore.com/download) (if not immediately obvious, check out the *More packages, platforms, versions and sources* link at the bottom right).