# how to use RegisterEventSource and ReportEvent function in an Ada program?

Tags: windows, ada, gnat

I am trying to access **RegisterEventSource** and **ReportEvent** function to write into windows event log in Ada.

Comment: What are the declarations of those two functions?  Where are they declared?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: i got this link to write into event logs http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=GUIExamples&CID=427

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen i have completed earlier stages but now i am woking on compilation

Comment: You need to show us at the very least the error messages the compiler is giving you, with some context (use `-gnatl` to intersperse error messages with listing). Have you installed the Win32Ada package someone asked about in [the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49918049/40851)? Do you know what a GNAT Project file (.gpr) is? (things will be much easier if you do).

Comment: yes i have installed win32ada packg. now i am only facing one issue here how to create .rbj @SimonWright

Comment: `.rbj` - it tells you in the adapower.com link.

Comment: yes i tried that one but that's not working anyway got the code working using dll instead of rbj. thanks for help.